# Toying around with Farseer Physics; the scaling is confusing me quite a bit

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I've dropped Farseer into my project and quickly started binding some circles to my enemies (this is a top-down) using `FixtureFactory.AttachCircle(...)`.

What's weird is I'm using regular pixel values to determine the radius of the circle and it's translating 1:1 into the size represented in Farseer.  For example `FixtureFactory.AttachCircle(32, 1f, body)` correctly translates into a circle 64 pixels in diameter.

Why is that?  Everything I've read on Google suggests to never go above 10 (meters) and to devise your own scale.

Am I missing some setting here to define the proportions of my world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Farseer engine uses MKS units (meters, kilorgrams, seconds).

This [article](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2011/02/farseer-physics-engines-meter-kilogram.html) gives a good example of how to convert this to simulation units.